# Android.mk Undefined Reference to "xxxx"

Tags: android

i am trying to create 2 so file with NDK-Build

libkdu_jni.so uses libkdu_v75R.so

i can create libkdu_v75R.so perfectly but i couldnt create libkdu_jni.so

here is my Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := libkdu_v75R
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := kdu_arch.cpp \
        kdu_threads.cpp \
        mq_encoder.cpp \
        mq_decoder.cpp \
        block_coding_common.cpp \
        block_encoder.cpp \
        block_decoder.cpp \
        encoder.cpp \
        decoder.cpp \
        ssse3_coder_local.cpp \
        avx_coder_local.cpp \
        compressed.cpp \
        codestream.cpp \
        blocks.cpp \
        kernels.cpp \
        messaging.cpp \
        params.cpp \
        colour.cpp \
        ssse3_colour_local.cpp \
        avx_colour_local.cpp \
        avx2_colour_local.cpp \
        analysis.cpp \
        synthesis.cpp \
        multi_transform.cpp \
        ssse3_dwt_local.cpp \
        avx2_dwt_local.cpp \
        roi.cpp \
        neon_coder_local.cpp \
        neon_colour_local.cpp \
        neon_dwt_local.cpp 

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := libkdu_jni
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := kdu_jni.cpp \
        kdu_aux.cpp \
        args.cpp \
        jp2.cpp \
        jpb.cpp \
        jpx.cpp \
        mj2.cpp \
        kdu_tiff.cpp \
        kdu_region_decompressor.cpp \
        ssse3_region_decompressor.cpp \
        kdu_region_compositor.cpp \
        kdu_stripe_decompressor.cpp \
        kdu_stripe_compressor.cpp \
        ssse3_stripe_transfer.cpp \
        avx2_stripe_transfer.cpp \
        kdu_cache.cpp \
        kdcs_comms.cpp \
        kdu_client_window.cpp \
        kdu_client.cpp \
        kdu_clientx.cpp \
        kdu_serve.cpp \
        kdu_servex.cpp 

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libkdu_v75R

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

ERRORS :

```
Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-21 is larger than android:minSdkVersion 8 in ./AndroidManifest.xml
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: kdu_jni <= args.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: kdu_jni <= jp2.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: kdu_jni <= jpb.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: kdu_jni <= jpx.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: kdu_jni <= mj2.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: kdu_jni <= kdu_tiff.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: kdu_jni <= kdu_region_decompressor.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: kdu_jni <= ssse3_region_decompressor.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: kdu_jni <= kdu_region_compositor.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: kdu_jni <= kdu_stripe_decompressor.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: kdu_jni <= kdu_stripe_compressor.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: kdu_jni <= ssse3_stripe_transfer.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: kdu_jni <= avx2_stripe_transfer.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: kdu_jni <= kdu_cache.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: kdu_jni <= kdcs_comms.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: kdu_jni <= kdu_client_window.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: kdu_jni <= kdu_client.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: kdu_jni <= kdu_clientx.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: kdu_jni <= kdu_serve.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: kdu_jni <= kdu_servex.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] SharedLibrary  : libkdu_jni.so
jni/kdu_threads.h:2978: error: undefined reference to 'kdu_core::kdu_thread_queue::~kdu_thread_queue()'
jni/kdu_threads.h:3173: error: undefined reference to 'kdu_core::kdu_thread_queue::schedule_job(kdu_core::kdu_thread_job*, kdu_core::kdu_thread_entity*, bool, int)'
**I CUT THIS PART**
jni/kdu_region_compositor.cpp:2066: error: undefined reference to 'kdu_core::kdu_codestream::set_persistent()'
jni/kdu_region_compositor.cpp:2067: error: undefined reference to 'kdu_core::kdu_codestream::augment_cache_threshold(int)'
jni/kdu_region_compositor.cpp:2089: error: undefined reference to 'kdu_core::kdu_codestream::set_persistent()'
jni/kdu_region_compositor.cpp:2090: error: undefined reference to 'kdu_core::kdu_codestream::augment_cache_threshold(int)'
jni/kdu_region_compositor.cpp:2108: error: undefined reference to 'kdu_core::kdu_codestream::restart(kdu_core::kdu_compressed_source*, kdu_core::kdu_thread_env*)'
jni/kdu_region_compositor.cpp:2139: error: undefined reference to 'kdu_core::kdu_codestream::change_appearance(bool, bool, bool, kdu_core::kdu_thread_env*)'
jni/kdu_region_compositor.cpp:2140: error: undefined reference to 'kdu_core::kdu_codestream::apply_input_restrictions(int, int, int, int, kdu_core::kdu_dims*, kdu_core::kdu_component_access_mode, kdu_core::kdu_thread_env*)'
jni/kdu_region_compositor.cpp:2173: error: undefined reference to 'kdu_core::kdu_thread_env::cs_terminate(kdu_core::kdu_codestream, int*)'
jni/kdu_region_compositor.cpp:2679: error: undefined reference to 'kdu_core::kdu_codestream::set_fast()'
jni/kdu_region_compositor.cpp:2680: error: undefined reference to 'kdu_core::kdu_codestream::set_fussy()'
jni/kdu_region_compositor.cpp:2682: error: undefined reference to 'kdu_core::kdu_codestream::set_resilient(bool)'
jni/kdu_region_compositor.cpp:2778: error: undefined reference to 'kdu_core::kdu_codestream::apply_input_restrictions(int, int, int, int, kdu_core::kdu_dims*, kdu_core::kdu_component_access_mode, kdu_core::kdu_thread_env*)'
jni/kdu_region_compositor.cpp:2781: error: undefined reference to 'kdu_core::kdu_codestream::get_num_components(bool)'
kdu_core::kdu_codestream_comment::get_text()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
/cygdrive/c/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/build-binary.mk:664: recipe for target 'obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libkdu_jni.so' failed
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libkdu_jni.so] Error 1
```

I cut some parts of error, because it s too long.

i am trying to create multiple .so file, firstly v75 then kdu_jni.so.

Because, kdu_jni uses v75.

How can i fix it android.mk.

Answer (score 0):

We used something like below to include static library while building so using ndk-build.

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libABC
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := <Path>/libABC.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

I'm not sure whether this works for you.